# How do I use colon to split in the middle of dataset?

Tags: python

A quick and easy question, but omehow I couldnt find the answer.
I am trying to split a dataset into training and testing. I have already used the sklearn train_test_split, but I want to try some things and tried to split specific values.
For example:

```
x = df.drop(['BDTI'], axis=1) 
y = df['BDTI'].iloc[0:]

X_train = x[40:]
y_train = y[40:]
X_test = x[:40]
y_test = y[:40]
```

Here I am looking at the first 40 values for testing.
How do I use this same logic to test for the values 40-80?

For testing its easy:
`X_test = x[50:80]`
But how do I structure it for training?

Edit:
I dont know if that question is asked wrong:
But I really just want to have my x data to consist of [:40] and [80:] but merged together. As easy as it sounds I cant get to it.

Comment: What datatype are `x` and `y`? Numpy arrays? Lists?

Comment: x and y are numpy arrays I created out of my df

Comment: Is your data is `pd.Dataframe` or `np.array` or `list`?

Comment: Sry maybe I misunderstod but my data looks like this:
```
x = df.drop(['BDTI'], axis=1) 
y = df['BDTI'].iloc[0:]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple [`concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html#numpy.concatenate) is all that's really needed here

```
import numpy as np

test_set = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
test_set_sample = np.concatenate((test_set[:3], test_set[5:7], test_set[9:])) #input a tuple
print(test_set_sample)
```

> [ 1  2  3  6  7 10]

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the [train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) function for that. It has the big advantage that your training set is not always at the beginning of the data, but randomly selected.

Also, you don't have to worry about indexing :)

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

Comment: Hey, thank you. I know this function already and have it in use. I just wanted to know how I can get the specific datapoints with "X_train = x[40:]" for inbetween data.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need the exact functionality, you can work with negative indices:

```
x = np.linspace(0,20)

split = 15
x_train = x[:split]
x_test = x[-len(x)+split:]

print(x_train)
print(x_test)
```

Comment: I will try this but from looking at it wouldnt it just give me the same problem?
I mean I want a training set for example for the data from 0-50 and 80-200 merged in one.
And a test set for the data from 50 to 80

Comment: Okay. Sorry misunderstood your question ☺️